# Two-step Login using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I wanted to load test an application but there is a login page with two pages. The app is not signed in, although the username and password are correct.
Maybe someone will have suggestions that I did not do it right

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your test plan is good, your app is informing you that the user doesn't exist:

[image]

Most probably the user you're using for `dev.storied.co` simply is not present at `stage.storied.co` environment so either choose another credentials or ask someone to create that user on the `stage` server.

Once you finish with test debugging don't forget to delete or at least disable all the [Listeners](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html), they [don't add any value and just consume valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/).

More information: [JMeter Best Practices - Reducing resource requirements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#lean_mean)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This user exists (but here I specified non-existent credentials), I can log in manually. It is possible that the password is left blank in the second step - in that case the notification will be the same

Comment: According to the [View Results Tree listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) you're sending not empty password, you can additionally double check the `${password}` variable value using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)